# PHP If else displaying wrong output as first entry value only . Code given

Tags: php, mysql, if-statement

Using Php to calculate charges - where in if:

> `$make` = Vehicle Make
>
> `$prod` = Vehicle Model

then it should display appropriate charges. However my code always displaying charges in the first entry.

For instance, if the code first entry has make as `Mahindra`, it will echo `$l`  `8150` in all product makes `Mahindra`, `Maruti`, `Mercedes Benz`, `Toyota` etc. Code is not respecting the logic.

If first entry is replaced with `Tata`, then it will echo `7500` despite any product make `Mahindra`, `Maruti`, `Mercedes Benz`, `Toyota`, `Tata` etc.

Any help would be appreciated.

**Code Modified**

```
<?php 
// logistics charges

$make = trim($this->prodDet->CatName);
$prod = trim($this->prodDet->product);

if ($make=="Mahindra") {
    $l= 8150;
}
else if($make=="Maruti Suzuki") {
    $l= 1500;
}
else if(($make=="Skoda") && ($prod=="Rapid")) {
    $l= 8000;
}
else if(($make=="Skoda") && ($prod=="Octavia")) {
    $l= 10000;
}
else if(($make=="Renault") && ($prod=="Duster")) {
    $l= 8500;
}
else if($make=="Tata") {
    $l= 7500;
}
else if($make=="Volkswagen") {
    $l= 7000;
}
else if ($make=="Toyota") {
    $l= 5750;
} 
else if ($make=="Mercedes Benz") {
    $l= 35000;
}

echo ($l);
?>
```

Comment: You have a *lot* of syntax errors and mistakes.

Comment: @JohnConde - Could you guide me 1 or 2 errors - so that can have a look

Comment: Use `==` instead of `=` in your if statements. Put quotes around your string values.

Comment: Unless all your unquoted vehicle models are constants, you need quotes around them. `($prod == "Rapid")`

Comment: @JohnConde- Sir - thanks - i have made necessary changes and modified - still desired output is not coming. I am novice in php - learning - thanks for letting know. Could you advise - whats missing now - Code modified

Comment: @Rasclatt - Sir - thanks - quotes been added - still desired output not coming

Comment: Where's the code that actually reads stuff from the database, assigns it to `$this->prodDet`, and loops over all the entries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using a function with nested `if` statements:

```
// If you use false as default values, it will not throw an error if
// either value is left empty
function FetchLogistics($make = false,$prod = false)
    {
        // Account for case. Make it all lower so it's all the same
        $make   =   strtolower($make);
        $prod   =   strtolower($prod);

        if($make == "mahindra")
            return 8150;
        elseif($make == "maruti suzuki")
            return 1500;
        // Just check once for make
        elseif($make == "skoda") {
                // Check for models now
                if($prod == "rapid")
                    return 8000;
                elseif($prod == "octavia")
                    return 10000;
            }
        elseif($make == "renault") {
                if($prod=="duster")
                    return 8500;
            }
        elseif($make == "tata")
            return 7500;
        elseif($make == "volkswagen")
            return 7000;
        elseif($make == "toyota")
            return 5750; 
        elseif($make == "mercedes benz")
            return 35000;

        // No matches will return false (empty)
        return false;       
    }

// Verify these two values are what you expect
$make = trim($this->prodDet->CatName);
$prod = trim($this->prodDet->product);

// Echo the returned value.
echo FetchLogistics($make,$prod);
```